# mark & reset in java BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I want to use `mark()` and `reset()` method to read the line before divider.

```
    String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(PATH);
    LineNumberReader br = new LineNumberReader(fr);
    String DIVIDER = "================================";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        boolean endOfObj = false;
        while (!line.trim().contains(DIVIDER)) {
            br.mark(line.length());
            line = br.readLine();  //return next line
        }
        br.reset();         
        line = br.readLine();
```

but line variable value is not the previous line of divider.
what is my problem is .
thank you

Comment: To begin with, you are `mark`ing after you have read the line, so the mark is after the line.

Comment: Not a great way to do it. Just remember the previous line each time around the loop, and use it when you break out of the loop.

Comment: thx @EJP, for some reason I should have go back to specific line again and store some extra data in my db,I wanted to handle it with mark() and reset(),How can I do it?

Comment: I've told you how to do it. What part of 'remember the previous line' don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using the following code?  I tidied up your code a bit, and put it into a method called `getPreviousLine()`.  I got the feeling that you were getting hung up on using `mark()` and `reset()`, so I just relied on pure logic and state to find the line before the divider.  If no divider is found, the method will return `null`.

```
String getPreviousLine(String PATH) {
    String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(PATH);
    LineNumberReader br = new LineNumberReader(fr);
    String DIVIDER = "================================";
    boolean endOfObj = false;
    String previousLine = br.readLine();

    if (previousLine == null) {
        return null;
    }

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.trim().contains(DIVIDER)) {
            endOfObj = true; // found the divider; break
            break;
        } else {
            previousLine = line; // advance your line pointer
        }
    }

    if (endOfObj) {
        return previousLine;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ,It really help. but what is my problem?How can I return pointer to specific line.Is it possible with mark() and reset() or not?

Comment: The `LineNumberReader` `mark()` and `reset()` methods are used to set a pointer to a file stream for the purpose of being able to reset to a given line.  Do you need a pointer into your file?

Comment: You can modify my code along the lines of what EJP said above in his comment.  Instead of keeping track of String `previousLine`, you can keep track of an `int` pointer.